# TINKER Molecular Modeling Troubleshooting

Tags: command-line

I am a student doing undergraduate research. I am using TINKER for modeling (Link: https://dasher.wustl.edu/tinker/). I am new to Linux and to this program and was wondering if anyone here could help me troubleshoot or help me find a place that will help me troubleshoot.

I currently have the program installed and can open it up using the path command in the Linux terminal (I have set this up this way). It asks me for my coordinates file and I enter the name of the file I want to test. This then prompts me with the same question. I keep entering the file name and get the same results, the program asking me to enter the coordinate files. Even someone who just knows about Linux programs. Could this be an issue with how I set it up? Thanks guys for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how to use the program will make it very difficult!

I downloaded TINKER and the example files, and if I use a totally bogus filename, TINKER just prompts for another filename. Not having error messages makes the program a little unfriendly to beginners.

If I specify a filename by path, eg. `~/tinker/fulldist/tinker/example/hexanes.xyz` I get a little blurb about hexanes, then prompted for another filename.  So, I don't think you have a setup issue, but you should probably find a fellow student who uses the program and ask for a short tutorial.